# Angular App with authentication that serves files only after login

Tags: node.js, angular, laravel, express

What I want to do is to have a login page for authentication (communicating with an API using JWT) and after that comes the tricky part, I only want to load the rest of the web site done in Angular 2+, after being logged.

I really only want the files(JS, CSS, HTML) to be served on the client after the login, this is important, because I don't want that files to be exposed to everyone in the WEB. Is something like this possible to do in an Node Angular app? If yes, how can it be implemented?

If it's not possible with Node, is it possible with other technology that works with angular (I'm thinking about laravel)?

Comment: which angular version do you mean, angular 1.x or angular2?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible but it won't be super simple.  The login logic for a page is often fairly complicated depending on what login technology you are using.  For example, if you are authenticating against the app itself (as opposed to a federated authentication) then you would need to collect and validate the username / password (e.g. make sure it isn't empty, etc.) and then send that to the server via some kind of post.  Depending on what kind of validation you need to do you might be able to achieve this with pure HTML5 or you might need some non-angular javascript.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are using a federated identity solution, then it can be really simple.  Just implement your server so that any unauthenticated request, including those for index.html, are redirected to your identity provider.

Comment: So, long story short, how to do it, and how much work it will be, will depend very much on how exactly you authenticate your users.  Are you using OpenID-Connect? Basic authentication? FORM post + cookies? Something custom?

Comment: for the authentication i want to use a FORM post and then use JWT to do the authenticated calls to the web service

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my precedent work that was the flow:Node was serving all the files after login.

Simply check if token is valid (token in the header), if it is allow access to the index.html otherwise redirect user to a login page.

**Don't include the login page to the angular app**. It can be a simple html file with an ajax call (jQuery) in order to send the credentials.
If credentials are OK, on the success response **redirect user to the index.html including token in headers for authentication**

Comment: +1 on having two separate "applications" where as one only serves for login purposes and the other one serves the actual application with business logic inside.

Comment: @IsraGab I'm not working now with Angular, but i think this is the answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To protect your module in an Angular app from even loading into browser, you should use `canLoad` guard like this:

```
path: 'customers',
canLoad: [AuthGuard],
loadChildren: 'app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
```

where `CustomersModule` is NgModule including all components you want to 'hide'. 
The code for this module will be separated in a chunk file and will only be loaded if the `AuthGuard.canLoad` returns `true`.

You can have a look at this simple app https://solid-flow.github.io/secure-app/customers and see in the dev console how different parts of the source code are loaded. The github repo can be found here https://github.com/solid-flow/secure-app

Answer (score 2):

With AngularCLI

1. Use WebPack to zip code

   `ng build --prod`
2. Use Routing config with simple AuthGuard implementation for unwanted access

   `{
       path: '',
       redirectTo: 'home',
       pathMatch: 'full',
   },
   {
       path: 'private',
       component: FullLayoutComponent,
       canActivate: [AuthGuard] // just auth users access
   }`

### AuthGuard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('TOKEN')) {
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this.router.navigate('login');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Breakdown your app into modules and and lazy load the authenticated bit.
Have the login page on the MainApp module then setup your routes like so:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: MainAppComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'protected-page',
            canActive: [AuthGuard],
            loadChildren: './protected-modul/protected.module#ProtectedModule'
        }
    ]
  }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the "front page" is the authentication page and after the server handle's the authentication you just serve the angular app. It all depends on how your main server is configured as to what it shows the user. Since you have it tagged express the "/" route would be the authentication page, a successful resolve of the authentication would then res.send the angular page. I haven't used angular but I'm sure it's possible.

See this tutorial:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular
It shows how to configure the express server and the angular one. You may need to adapt it a little to your needs but it should get you 99% of the way there.

Worst case just make 2 instances of the express app (app = express) && (app2 = express) and have the second one start serving files (on a separate port) after authenticating with the first one. It may not be pretty but that wasn't the question. :)

Comment: Tks for the answer, i updated my question because it was a little incomplete.

Comment: After taking a few pokes at it, it isn't as easy as I had assumed. Angular seems to grab the route before express does.

Comment: "Angular seems to grab the route.."?